# ruby basic regex pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

Hello I'm trying to extract from a server log some data by this criteria all `GET`s but at the output I want to get from [GET] path [protocol] only the path

regex:

```
line.match(/[a-z0-9]*GET \s*([\/a-zA-Z]+)/)
```

fix.rb

```
...
GET /edu/languages/google
GET /edu/languages/google
GET /baz/img/techtalk
...
```

So, need the GET part removed... any advices? thank you

Comment: http://www.rubular.com - I'm not the creator but I find it really useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First tip, use [rubular.com](http://rubular.com).

Short answer

```
res = line.match(/^GET(.*)/)[1]
```

Meaning: (if you need it)

1. `^` indicates match `GET` at the beginning of the string
2. `()` indicates capture the result of that part in a recoverable object
3. `.*` means capture everything, since that is what you need.
4. `[1]` means get the second item from the list of the matched elements, 0 being the entire string that is matched.

Iterate in loop if required

Comment: Please don't "share" books. There is plenty of documentation available online without needing to resort to that. The authors of books worth sharing deserve being rewarded for their hard work. You take away their incentive, and interest, in writing future books by "sharing", which hurts us all.

Comment: I would write this as `res = line[/^GET (\S+)/, 1]`.

Comment: Yup, sharing name of the book is one thing, and sharing the book is another. If you find yourself in the need of a constant reference for a book, you should consider owning it, a much happier learning curve

Comment: @theTinMan that was nice, hadn't really seen this, but it struck at once. very nice

Comment: Look at [`String[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [`String[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D). They're able to do a lot of things, and should all be intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the match data you want with the brackets operator

```
"GET /hello".match(/[a-z0-9]*GET \s*([\/a-zA-Z]+)/)[1]
 => "/hello"
```